# show pdf in browser from HTTP.get('/my_pdf')

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, ruby, isomorphic, hyperstack

Ηι!

I use *HTTP.get('/ehde_pdf')* that through routes.rb calls a controller method that executes this code:

```
send_data(
          "#{Rails.root}/tmp/ehde_pdf.pdf",
          filename: "your_custom_file_name.pdf",
          type: "application/pdf"
      )
```

which returns pdf data to the browser, but it's doesn't show up in our page as download prompt.
I can see from e.g. Mozilla Developer Tools -> Network that browser gets file data and I can download it with double-click:
[image]

Is there any way that I can get file data from HTTP.get('/ehde_pdf') and show the download prompt directly?

Thanx!!!

Answer (score 0):

***Correction***: the controller code is

```
send_file(
      "#{Rails.root}/tmp/ehde_pdf.pdf",
      filename: "your_custom_file_name.pdf",
      type: "application/pdf"
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a [javascript blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) in this case. You can do something like this:

```js
(...some api call here)
  .then(res => {
    const blob = new Blob([res.data]);
    const link = document.createElement(triggerTag);
    link.href = window.url.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.download = 'some_file_name';
    link.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href);
  })
  .catch(....);
```

This way you can programmatically trigger the download when the user clicks on a button to download the pdf.